# jqgrid enable disable multiselect on button click

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i wanted to enable and disable the multiselect option of jqgrid at runtime (button click)
i have tried "gridContainer.jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb');" this hides the checkbox columns only which breaks the UI of the header row.

Tried setting the multiselect:true using SetGridParams but giving "cm is not defined" error.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has managed to do it [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideMultiselectColumn.htm).